# Two Maven project with public module

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I have a project that devided into three pieces, `PCommon`, `PWebapp` and `PAdminConsole`. `PWebapp` and `PAdminConsole` are dynamic web project in eclipse, `PCommon` is java project, and both two web project will use the api in `PCommon` as a jar file in lib folder.

In the past,I added `import project` in build path, I used `Ant` to compile and build `PWebapp` and `PAdminConsole` and in both `build.xml` file there is

`<ant antfile="${common}/../build.xml" inheritAll="false"></ant>`

to make `PCommon` into a jar file.

Now I will change all my projects to `Maven Project`. But I don't know how to make two web projects contain one public module, and how to package my `PCommon` into a jar file automaticlly when I run `package` maven command to package one web project.

Now I always deploy my `PCommon.jar` on nexus server. and then add `dependcy` in `pom.xml` in web projects. But I think there is no sense to deploy the jar on the public server, so I think it isn't the right way to archieve this goal. Is there any way that is more convenient?

I know I can make a parent project with a parent `pom.xml`. But I have two web project need the module, the `pom.xml` in `PCommon` can only extends one parent, can't it?

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to achieve. Could you elaborate a little bit?

Comment: @AndréStannek I want to package the common project into a jar automaticly when I build the web project like `<ant antfile=xxx/>` and I dont't want run mvn install in common project to install it first everytime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common way to resolve dependencies in Maven is using a repository. The first time a dependency is needed, it is downloaded from your repository and installed in the repository on your local machine. If a dependency is not available in the remote repository it has to be installed to your local one in some other way. There are a few other ways to resolve depenencies without using the repositories but I wouldn't suggest to use the.

To make this a little more convenient, you can use a proper IDE. I use Eclipse with the [m2e](https://www.eclipse.org/m2e/) plugin. It supports something called "workspace resolution", which should be enabled by default. It scans your workspace for other Maven projects before falling back to the repository lookup. This has the advantage that every change you make in your common project is immediatly available in the other projects. I think it also gets installed to your local repository in the background but I'm not sure. Anyway you don't have to worry about it yourself.

Something similar works with IntelliJ IDEA but I don't have that much experience with it. I'm sure Netbeans has some kind of Maven support too.